# BroadcastReceiver components are not allowed to register to receive intents

Tags: android

I am trying to listen to a very specific SMS sent from a particular sender containing a particular keyword. For that, I have created a BroadcastReceiver which binds to `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` through manifest.

If I find that particular sender sending SMS containing that keyword, I need to send the SMS from my application. I have done that in my application through `onReceive()` function.

The problem is that I want to listen to SMS_SENT and SMS_DELIVERED events to know that if sms was successfully sent/delivered or not. For that , I am registering these receivers through

```
context.registerReceiver(smsSentReceiver, new  IntentFilter(Consts.SENT));
context.registerReceiver(smsDeliveredReceiver, new IntentFilter(Consts.DELIVERED));
```

Though, I have instantiated a seperate `AsyncTask` from the `onReceive` method to do this job, but still I am getting the error below
`BroadcastReceiver components are not allowed to register to receive intents`

Should I use `IntentService` instead of `AsyncTask` from the `onReceive`?
or
Should I instantiate an `IntentService` from `AsyncTask` executed in `onReceive`?

Comment: What do you mean you have instantiatd a separate AsyncTask o do this job? Can you post more of the log cat and maybe some more code? I can only think of a few situations in which this error occurss but I need to see more.

Comment: See the source code here: https://github.com/madhur/MapMyLocation/blob/master/src/in/co/madhur/mapmylocation/tasks/LocationTask.java

Comment: Here I have an AsyncTask executed in onRecieve method of a reciever. the error is at RegisterReciever call

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can handle multiple broadcast types in one Receiver, so you could simply direct the send and delivery `Intent`s to the same one that's handling `SMS_RECEIVED`, and then dispatch the work accordingly from there; e.g., to a `Service` or `Worker`.

Since your SMS Receiver is already statically registered in the manifest, just make sure that your send and delivery `Intent`s explicitly target your Receiver class, and you won't need to change anything in the manifest. For example:

```java
public static final String ACTION_SMS_SENT = "com.example.app.SMS_SENT";
public static final String ACTION_SMS_DELIVERED = "com.example.app.SMS_DELIVERED";


Intent sendIntent =
        new Intent(ACTION_SMS_SENT, null, context, SmsReceiver.class);

PendingIntent sendPending =
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, sendIntent, …);
```

In the Receiver, first check the action, then decide where to go from there:

```java
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        switch (intent.getAction()) {
            case Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION:
                …
                break;

            case ACTION_SMS_SENT:
                …
                break;

            case ACTION_SMS_DELIVERED:
                …
                break;

            default:
                …
        }
    }
}
```